# Moment Generating Function of $\chi^2_\nu$

Tags: probability, statistics, moment-generating-functions

(a) Compute the moment generating function of $\chi^2_\nu$ random variable where $\chi^2_\nu$ is defined as $X\sim \chi^2_\nu$  if and only if 
$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2^{\frac{\nu}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2}) }x^{\frac{\nu}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}} & x\geq 0\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

This is my solution so far.

$M_X(s)=E(e^{sx})$
Thus $M_X(s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{2^{\frac {\nu}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2}) }x^{\frac{\nu}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}e^{sx}$
Taking out the constants we have $\frac{1}{2^{\frac {\nu}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2}) } \int_0^\infty x^{\frac{\nu}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}e^{sx} $
Simplifying yields $\frac{1}{2^{\frac {\nu}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2}) }e^{s-\frac{1}{2}} \int_0^\infty x^{\frac{\nu}{2}-1}e^x $
(I am not sure whether or not I combined my $e$ terms correctly)
Now, if all is so far correct the simplified integral, without the constants, to me looks like
$\frac{\nu}{2}-1$ $\Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2}-1)$ however not fully since in the integral I have an $x$ not a $-x$.

Please help me figure out my mistakes.

(b) Use these moment generating functions give a simpler demonstration that if $X$ ∼ $\chi^2_\nu$ and $Y$ ∼ $\chi^2_k$ are independent, then $X +Y$ ∼ $\chi^2_{\nu+k}$.
Using the answer from below
Since $M_X(s)=(1-2s)^{-\frac{\nu}{2}}$ for $X$ ~ $\chi^2_\nu$ it follows that $M_Y(s)=(1-2s)^{-\frac{k}{2}}$ for $Y$ ~ $\chi^2_k$
Using the property $M_{X+Y}(s)=M_X(s)M_Y(s)$
We can conclude that $X+Y$ ~ $\chi^2_{\nu+k} = (1-2s)^{-\frac{\nu}{2}}(1-2s)^{-\frac{k}{2}}=(1-2s)^{-\frac{1}{2}(\nu+k)}$

Comment: Stop asking all of your 170B homework questions on MSE, seriously.

Comment: @Adam Students are often asking for HW help here. We have THOROUGHLY discussed this in Meta. The conclusion was that eventual violations of academic code are to be handled at the academic institutions. We do not have the resources to police that. For the most part we require the askers to explain what they have tried, and where they have problems + giving such "context". There is a strong sentiment not to give copy/pastable solutions. We have many teachers here who are in agreement with the policy. Not all of them are happy with it, but for the most part it is a working compromise.

Comment: So, my advice is that you bring this up with the faculty, and discuss how to deal with it. In many places they are confident in their ability to catch the copycats :-) May be the weight of homework in the grade will go down as a consequence? Eventual copyright matters (to the extent that you actually can have a copyright to a standard exercise) should be handled with [the SE staff](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service). The site, of course, will comply with DMCA. But we the volunteer diamond moderators (largely coming from outside the US) do not have the resources to handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $e^{sx}e^{-\frac{x}{2}} = e^{(s-\frac{1}{2})x}\neq e^{s-\frac{1}{2}}e^x$. Instead
\begin{align*}
M_X(s) &= \int_0^\infty e^{sx} \cdot\frac{1}{2^{\frac{\nu}{2}}\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu}{2}\right)} x^{\frac{\nu}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2^{\frac{\nu}{2}}}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu}{2}\right)}x^{\frac{\nu}{2}-1} e^{\left(s-\frac{1}{2}\right)x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}-s\right)^{-\frac{\nu}{2}}}{2^{\frac{\nu}{2}}}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu}{2}\right)}\left(\frac{1}{2}-s\right)^{\frac{\nu}{2}}x^{\frac{\nu}{2}-1} e^{-\left(\frac{1}{2}-s\right)x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{[(1/2)(1-2s)]^{-\frac{\nu}{2}}}{2^{\frac{\nu}{2}}}\cdot 1\\
&= (1-2s)^{-\frac{\nu}{2}}
\end{align*}
where the integrand in the third line is the pdf of a $\operatorname{Gamma}\left(\frac{\nu}{2}, \frac{1}{2}-s\right)$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I have added one more part to the question, and tried to answer it using the result which you obtained. Could you please tell me whether or not it is correct?

Comment: Yeah, that looks mostly right, but I would rephrase it as: Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $M_{X+Y}(s) = M_X(s)M_Y(s) = (1-2s)^{\nu/2}(1-2s)^{k/2} = (1-2s)^{\frac{\nu+k}{2}}$, which implies that $X+Y\sim \chi_{\nu+k}^2$. Basically, I think there is an issue with notation when you write "$X+Y\sim \chi^2_{\nu+k} =$", in particular that equals sign. Also, you can use `\sim` instead of the tilde key in $X+Y\sim \chi^2_{\nu+k}$ `$X+Y\sim \chi^2_{\nu+k}$`.

Comment: Sounds great, thank you for your help and advice!

Comment: No problem, good luck! By the way, what is your class called, or what book are you using, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: It's the second part of probability theory. The ISBN is 188652940X, but the professor writes his own problems.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the info!